# Company hub and shared files in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm writing company hub app on Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime. Is there any possibility to access shared file via token?

Windows Phone Silverlight example:

```
foreach (var installedPackage in InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher())
{
    var thumbnailToken = installedPackage.GetThumbnailToken();
    await SharedStorageAccessManager.CopySharedFileAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "thumbnail.jpg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting, thumbnailToken);
}
```

The problem is that in Runtime there is no SharedStorageAccessManager class. Is there any replacement class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows Phone 8.1 , company hub app has to be a Silverlight app. Universal apps can be company app but not company hub.